# I want to create class objects using for loop in C++

Tags: c++

I have a class named CLASS, lets say.

using for loop for `for(int i=0;i<10;i++)`
i want to create 10 CLASS object named class1, class2, class3....

how do i do that?

Comment: Use a container such as `std::vector` to store multiple objects of your class.

Comment: Why not `std::vector<CLASS>` or `std::array<CLASS, 10>`?

Comment: Object *names* are fixed at compile-time, and don't even exist (and can't be generated) at runtime. You probably want an array of objects: `CLASS array[10];`, or `std::vector<CLASS>`, or something similar.

Comment: Objects don't have names, variables do.

Comment: You can't, since any variables created within the loop cease to exist when the loop ends.  You can create an array or some other container (`vector`, `list`, etc) containing ten objects of type `CLASS`, and access elements `array[0]`, `array[1]`, ..... `array[9]`  (array indexing is zero-based).     A loop isn't necessary to create such an array, but - once the array exists - a loop can be used to access those elements sequentially.     Any basic textbook on C++ will be able to give more information on how to do that, so try reading one.

Answer (score 0):

You can create a array of the object.

```
for(int i=0;i<10;i++){
    Object[i] = ObjectName;  
}
```

This will the simplest way

Comment: You're assuming that the array exists.   The question was how to create the objects, not initialise them once created.