# How to dynamically creat variables in a loop(c++)

Tags: c++

I want to create some variables in a loop,e.g.

```
for(int i = 0; i < _vector.size(); i++) //_vector is a vector struct
{
  auto v = _vector.at(i);
  auto xi = get_name(v);   //how to create x0,x1,x2,x3.....dynamically in this loop
}
```

anyone knows how to do it like that?
thanks very much!

Comment: Very unclear what you're asking

Comment: I think the OP misunderstands what the [auto](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/auto) keyword means.

Comment: Not possible in standard C++.   For a similar question, refer https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61818717/i-want-to-create-class-objects-using-for-loop-in-c#comment109343131_61818717

Comment: if you are looking for create string x0, x1, x2, where x0, x1, x2 are variables, that is not possible.

Comment: OP, think about how you'd use those variables outside the loop, even if it were possible to create them. Since they where not defined in compile time, the compiler knows nothing about them. In C++, that doesn't make sense. But since you're talking about dynamic variables anyway, you can just use a map, where the key is your "variable name" and your value is its value.

Comment: Since 2011, you would better write a simpler for loop: for(int v : _vector)

Answer (score 2):

If you want to reference these variables as x1, x2, etc., it would be better to create a vector to store these.

The code below is written to support integers, however, this can be replaced with another data type.

```
vector<int> x;
for(int i = 0; i < _vector.size(); i++) //_vector is a vector struct
{
  auto v = _vector.at(i);
  x.push_back(get_name(v));   //sets the value of x.at(0), x.at(1)...
}
```

Comment: but no matching constructor for initialization of my data type

Comment: @yisun03 You should be able to use your data type in a vector. Could we see the code behind the data type?

Comment: the data type is z3::expr ,z3 is a  theorem prover,i use it's c++ api, z3::expr does not has default constructor

Comment: @yisun03 It might be helpful if you posted the code for your `get_name` function then. I would suggest submitting a new question with this information as you'd be more likely to attract someone who's more familiar with this library.